# How do I change data-magnify-src attribute of HTML element with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've tried

```
$(elem).prop('data-magnify-src', 'change')

$(elem).data('magnify-src', 'change')
```

This is my snippet. I hope I am not doing something dumb. I really thought it would work.

```js
 $().ready(function () {

    $('.img-miniatura').click(function(e){

   
    $('#bigImg').prop('data-magnify-src', 'new'  );


    });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
<img data-magnify-src="old" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/uImwY.jpg?s=48&g=1" id="bigImg"/>
</div>

<div>
<div>click the image below and change the data attribute of the image above</div>
<img class='img-miniatura'  src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/uImwY.jpg?s=48&g=1"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code seems correct. Could you share a reproducible pen or full code where it fails ?

Comment: I am changing the src and data-maginify-src attributes of the element inside the same block of code the src changes but data-maginify-src doesn't. I don't believe it is a typo. But I will try to make the code reproducible. Besides no error in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.attr`, not `.prop`

For example:

```
$(function(){
  $('.img-miniatura').click(function(e){
    $('#bigImg').attr('data-magnify-src', 'new');
  });
});
```

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/1hbkv75q/2/

Comment: Yes, I've used attr before posting this question but it didn't work, I think I commited a typo. After losing my entire morning, and just before seeing your answers I decided to try again and it worked. I was about to submit an answer but I am glad you did it.